# get folder changes using vb.net or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

is there way to keep change tracking for folders in .net ? for example if a file added to folder some code in my app gone to run ? something like triggers but for windows form app?

Comment: Well, usually MSDN is a good start point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are describing the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. It watches the file system, and raises events when things change, allowing you to run your code in the event handlers to process the file/folder changes you need.

There's an example of using on the MSDN page linked, here it is (in the unlikely event the link goes stale):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

public class Watcher
{

    public static void Main()
    {
       Run();
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        // If a directory is not specified, exit program.
        if(args.Length != 2)
        {
            // Display the proper way to call the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe (directory)");
            return;
        }

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = args[1];
        /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
           the renaming of files or directories. */
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        // Only watch text files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Wait for the user to quit the program.
        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while(Console.Read()!='q');
    }

    // Define the event handlers.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
       Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
    }
}
```